# Is there a tool that we could use to compare two Jars at Binary/Byte code level?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-compiler-api

The idea is to compare two jars and see if they were generated from same source and compare if they're identical at Binary/Byte code level. Also if they're both compiled with the same compiler i.e. Eclipse JDT or JIT etc compiler.

I've looked at Apache Common BCEL, but it only does comparison after decomposing the original byte-code into source code and then it compares it like diff tool; that compares text line-byline, but what I would like is to compare the byte-code without being decomposed/rearranged to source code and then compare.

I was looking at how we could compare straight binary/byte code comparison!!!!

Free tools/API recommendation would be good :)
Ta

Answer (score 3):

you may try any of these  following jar comparator tool as based on yours requirement..

[extradata-product](http://www.extradata.com/products/jarc/)     free for personal use

[zardiff](http://zipdiff.sourceforge.net/)     on sourceforge.

[japi-compilance-checker](http://ispras.linuxbase.org/index.php/Java_API_Compliance_Checker)  os based

[pkgdiff](http://lvc.github.io/pkgdiff/)

Comment: `extradata-product` does comparison after its decompiled, which is not what I want. Just to re-iterate. I want to compare the original byte-code.

Comment: for checking backward binary and source-level compatibility of a Java library API you can go for japi-compilance-checker...

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Beyond Compare (beware that it is not a free application)

http://www.scootersoftware.com/

Comment: The benefit of using Beyond Compare is that you can create your own file format handler simply by specifying an external command line to execute.  I have used this capability to create a `.class` comparer that diffs decompiler output from Procyon.  A simple tweak to the command line arguments would produce a diff of the formatted bytecode instead.