# Does compiling Java with different versions of JDK and same target and source version guaranties same execution?

Tags: java, java-8

We are going to update our CI system that creates builds from Java 7 to Java 8. Later we would like to migrate projects to Java 8 one by one. Of course, we would like to be able to create bugfix releases for older versions that still use Java 7.

Can we be sure that no issues will appear if we transfer building same source, target version and source version from JDK 7 to JDK 8? We did testing on development machines without any issues.

Before that, we are also gradually updating deployment servers from JRE 7 to JRE 8.

Note that we would like to keep single Java JDK installation on CI system, it gets complicated otherwise.

**To make it more clear:**
I am more interested in same execution outcome, not so much about the same bytecode. Same bytecode would just confirm the first (running on same JRE), if I understand that correctly.

We will not use Java 8 features in code until we have all deployments running on Java 8. So compatibility is not an issue.

Comment: I'm going to assume it won't generate the same bytecode since compiling with the same JDK may not generate the same bytecode either. The execution outcomes of the same code targeting the same target and source version will be the same though.

Comment: I take it what you really want to know is not whether the two class files will have the same byte code in a byte-for-byte comparison, but whether all the class files created with jdk8 with -source/-target set to 1.7 will be *compatible* with all older class files, utilities, frameworks, etc. Is that right?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Not quite.  You'd also need to set the bootclasspath to JDK 7 explicitly; `-source`/`-target` set language levels but _not_ library levels.

Comment: @LouisWasserman's comment raises a *hugely* important point. Be careful about this. Libraries matter.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou Exactly right. Compatible AND same execution because we don't want to hit any strange bugs because compiler works differently in different JDKs.

Comment: So I guess answer goes into direction that bytecode is the same in general and execution also but we can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Consider updating the question title to match the clarification in the body.  (It's good you recognized the XY problem, but I was about to go find an example that would prove a _No_ answer to your question title question.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Does compiling Java with different versions of JDK and same target and source version produce same bytecode?

There are no guarantees.

Indeed, two .class files created from the same source code using the same compiler with the same options on the same hardware will have the same bytecode, but the files may still be different because of embedded compilation timestamp attributes.

However, if you wanted to compare notionally equivalent bytecode files, this Q&A offers some possible leads:

- [Is there a tool that we could use to compare two Jars at Binary/Byte code level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742668/is-there-a-tool-that-we-could-use-to-compare-two-jars-at-binary-byte-code-level)

---

I expect that you *will* find that there are some differences between the bytecodes generated by Java 7 and Java 8 compilers, but that this won't matter.

Answer (score 4):

As specified in this [blog@https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/source_target_class_file_version](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/source_target_class_file_version).

> Given the same source code, compilers from different releases configured to use the same source and same target (and same bootclasspath!), can still generate different class files because of bug fixes or changes to compiler-internal contracts.

**But this problem will not happen to you since you have the same compiler that compiles to different target versions.** It just have to emit the specific magic number and byte code compatible for that version. It looks like keeping your version in 1.8 and specifying the target that is either a lower or equal version would work. Looking at this past defect that was addressed, it appears it should work and Oracle works to fix such incompatibilities.
http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4175911

Additional resources that should help:

1. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077388/core-java/what-version-is-your-java-code.html?page=2
2. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html

Comment: The OP is asking about different `javac` versions and the same source / target levels.  Not the same `javac` and different source / target levels.

Comment: "single Java JDK installation on CI system" inferred one javac.

Comment: That means one at a time.  He also says: *"We are going to update our CI system that creates builds from Java 7 to Java 8."*

Comment: I dont think the build server need to have multiple JDK's to create builds from Java 7 to Java 8.

Comment: I agree. But that is not the point. The OP is worried about what happens when he replaces Java 7 with Java 8.  Specifically ... does the upgrade may cause problems because the Java 7 javac and Java 8 javac are generating different bytecodes.  My take is that 1) it is quite likely that there will be a difference in the bytecodes, but 2) it is unlikely that this will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

yeah!! it actually depends on the code. in some cases it might generate a different bytecode but normally it generate the same bytecode in normal cases.

Different JDKs will have different Java compilers which may emit different    bytecodes for the same source code. The javac compiler has evolved over time.

Different major versions of the Java often emit class files that conform to different versions of the classfile specification.

Even if you restrict yourself to one JDK installation, two runs of the compiler on the same source file will produce non-identical .class files.